# Chrome does not sound in Freya

Tags: release-freya, google-chrome, sound

I don't know what's wrong, it was working normally but now Chrome does not play any sound, if I go to YouTube and play a video I can't hear the sound. What could be the problem?

Comment: have you checked System Settings > Sound > Applications?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any sound that your computar can play?

note, there is a sound setting where the application that play sound can be activated or desactivated.

[image: Sound setting]

Comment: Actually Chrome wasn't the problem, HDMI second screen was. I reported it as a bug here -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1512738